# Is there an ideal $J$ with $Ann(J)=0$ such that $J\subseteq I_1\cap\cdots\cap I_n$?

Tags: lie-algebras, ideals, nonassociative-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra and $I_1,\dots,I_n$ ideals in $L$ with $Ann(I_k)=0$ for all $k=1,\dots,n$. Of course, $I_1\cap\cdots\cap I_n\neq0$.
I would like to know if there exists an ideal $J\subseteq I_1\cap\cdots\cap I_n$ such that $Ann(J)=0$.

I'll appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Is $Ann(I)=C_L(I)$ just the centrlizer of $I$ in $L$?

Comment: Yes. $Ann(I):=\{y\in L : [y, I]=0 \}$

Comment: To get a feeling for this, can you give a non-trivial ($n \ge 2$) example?

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg, is it a trivial example for you to take any semiprime Lie algebra $L$?